# JS : why isn't this value passing from one function to another?

Tags: javascript, function, return, arguments

Further to a post earlier, I'm working with `return` , and returning a value from one function to another.  I'm a little stuck at the moment.

Below, I'm trying to pass the result of `userName` and `validated` variables into `userCheck` function as the arguments.  Something isn't going right, could anyone provide guidance please?  Thank you.

```
var checkInput = function (userName) {
    var validated = true;       // For use later to decide whether userCheck runs.  
    var userName = prompt("What is your name?");
    var checkType = typeof userName;        // Save whether it's a string, number, null, or object.

    if (checkType == "object") { 
        console.log("You clicked cancel."); 
        validated = false; 
        }       //If cancel is clicked , do this.

        else if (userName =="") {
             console.log("You didn't enter a name"); 
             validated = false; 
            }   // If they just press enter, do this.

            else if (isNaN(userName) == false) { 
            validated = false;
            console.log("That's a number"); 
            }   //If it's a number, do this.

                else { 
                    return userName; 
                    }   //Otherwise, return userName for use elsewhere.
};   

var userCheck = function(userEntry, validated) {
    var userName = userEntry;
    var validated = validated; 
    var correctMessage = (`Welcome back, ${userEntry}.`);
    if (validated == true && userName == "alan" || userName == "rachel") { console.log(correctMessage); }

};

userCheck(checkInput());
```

Comment: It looks like you need to revisit variable scopes in JS. Here are a few recommendations on the topic: [Definition-MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) , [Explained - MSN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/variable-scope-javascript) and finally [More on Scope-MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Comment: What's the purpose of `var validated = validated;`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply and the links.  I'm still within my first couple of weeks of learning so i'll definitely give those a look over!

As for the var validated = validate , it was my (rather odd), attempt at pulling the value of validated from the checkInput function to use in userCheck (if it was false, give an error message type thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return those variables. Try the following.

```
var checkInput = function(userName) {
    var validated = true; // For use later to decide whether userCheck runs.  
    var userName = prompt("What is your name?");
    var checkType = typeof userName; // Save whether it's a string, number, null, or object.

    if (checkType == "object") {
        console.log("You clicked cancel.");
        validated = false;
    } //If cancel is clicked , do this.
    else if (userName == "") {
        console.log("You didn't enter a name");
        validated = false;
    } // If they just press enter, do this.
    else if (isNaN(userName) == false) {
        validated = false;
        console.log("That's a number");
    } //If it's a number, do this.
    return {
        userName: userName,
        validated: validated
    };
};

var userCheck = function(object) {
    var userName = object.userName;
    var validated = object.validated;
    var correctMessage = (`Welcome back, ${userName}.`);
    if (validated == true && userName == "alan" || userName == "rachel") {
        console.log(correctMessage);
    }

};

userCheck(checkInput());
```

This will now return an object with the `userName` and `validated`. Then in your `userCheck` function you look at the values within that object. This is because you can only return 1 thing in a function. So we need to get both of those variables into 1 item.

Comment: Ahh, I haven't done anything with objects yet.  I guess that would have been a lot easier for me to figure out if I'd studied that yet?  
Also, can only return 1 thing from a function - first news to me, thanks! 

I feel like I was vaguely on the right lines, just a little lost with what to call return on where, and how to implement it lol!

Comment: Awesome! If that makes sense and it helped you consider accepting the answer so it can help others. Let me know if any part doesn't make sense or anything. Happy coding!!